# Was there evidence that she existed before Season 3?

Tags: sherlock

In the fourth season of BBC *Sherlock* we learn that there is a third Holmes child.

We learn that there is a lot of references in Season Three that were tied to Eurus: Redbeard, the East Wind, Mycroft stating "You know what happened to the other one", etc.

However, was there any evidence prior to Season Three that Eurus existed?  Or did we only get evidence starting in Season Three?

Answer (score 3):

No. There wasn't any direct reference to Eurus Holmes in the first 2 seasons, only RedBeard is mentioned. However, her entrance had been planned for a long time. This is evident from the interview [Steven Moffat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Moffat) gave to [RadioTimes](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2017-01-08/the-origins-of-sherlocks-euros--and-how-her-arrival-has-been-foreshadowed-since-series-three).

> "It started as a joke years ago there was going to be a line in the first season where we were sketching in the Holmes family. But we thought we won't do too much, and thank God we didn't, because it has given us this place to go."

In another interview with [Metro](http://metro.co.uk/2017/01/15/heres-what-the-cast-and-crew-had-to-say-about-sherlock-series-4-finale-the-final-problem-6381837/), Moffat revealed the joke that never made it to broadcast.

> "We made and, thank God, cut a reference in [2010] episode The Great Game... where Mycroft is explaining he is smarter than Sherlock, and then Mycroft goes onto say, ‘My sister of course...’ and then gets cut off. It was just a joke, just a passing thing. Thank God we cut that, because we could keep the secret a bit longer. The madness, that we thought would never sustain, of hinting that Sherlock’s got a brother and then pulling, frankly, in the circumstances, the only twist you can – which is it’s actually Sherlock’s sister."

### Appearances of Eurus Holmes

**Series Three**

- "His Last Vow" (referenced)

**Series Four**

- "The Six Thatchers" (as the woman on the bus)
- "The Lying Detective" (as John's therapist & Culverton Smith's daughter; identity revealed)
- "The Final Problem"